# Result of query (mysqli) not showing with PHP, although it works in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm running following query in phpMyAdmin and I receive the expected results, but when I try to display it with PHP I can't see anything in browser and any error message as well!

Hier the code:

```
// Displays the erros. 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Here the query
$query = "
SELECT
    p.auth,
    p.nr,
    p.kind,
    (SELECT i.family FROM table02 i WHERE p.family = i.family LIMIT 1) family,
    (SELECT group_concat(i.class) FROM table03 i WHERE p.family = i.family) class,
    (SELECT a.appl FROM table04 a WHERE p.family = a.family) appl,
    p.date,
    (SELECT s.sim FROM table05 s WHERE p.family = s.num2 LIMIT 1) sim
FROM
    table01 p
WHERE
    p.family = 1
ORDER BY sim DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error());

// Echoes the table with the result of the query.
echo "<table>\n";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['auth']$row['nr']$row['kind']."</td><td>".$row['family']."</td><td>".$row['class']."</td><td>"."</td><td>".$row['appl']."</td><td>"."</td><td>".$row['date']."</td><td>"."</td><td>".$row['sim']."</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

First of all, what I should do to receive a feedback from PHP showing the possible wrong lines of the code?

Moreover, is there any problem by display of the table? I have a very similar code that display another query very well. The only difference is that the query is not so complex like this one we have here. But I don't believe that the query is wrong, because it works fine in phpMyAdmin giving me the expected results.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Typo right? Missing semi-colon at the end of `...$row['sim']."</td>\n"`

Comment: Also, missing connection data?

Comment: That's already assumed `mysqli_query($link, $query)` @D.Kasipovic

Comment: Assumed meaning you are setting the `$link` properly but have just ommited data on purpose? Also, `$row['auth']$row['nr']$row['kind']` can't work, it should be `$row['auth'].$row['nr'].$row['kind']`? Is this the real script or an example?

Comment: @Fred -ii- What you mean with Typo?
There is a semi-colon in the original code. I forgot to type it. I've just edited it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome; just checking. Others would have probably signaled it also.

Comment: @D. Kasipovic the connection data comes through a include. Here you are:
 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "user";
 $pass = "**********";
 $database = "db";

$link = mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$pass","$database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

Comment: And `$row` part that I wrote?

Comment: @D. Kasipovic. You're right. With . it works! Many thanks!

Comment: [`Worthy of an answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922468/result-of-query-mysqli-not-showing-with-php-although-it-works-in-phpmyadmin#comment34989226_22922468) I'd say ;-)

Comment: Could also change your query into: `SELECT p.auth, p.nr, p.kind, t2.family AS family, group_concat(t3.class) AS class, a.appl AS appl, p.date, s.sim AS sim FROM table01 p JOIN table02 t2 ON p.family = t2.family JOIN table03 t3 ON p.family = t3.family JOIN table04 t4 ON p.family = t4.family JOIN table05 t5 ON p.family = t5.num2  WHERE p.family = 1 ORDER BY sim DESC`

Comment: @D.Kasipovic and Fred -ii- Thank you guys. I'm new here by Stack Overflow. The power and cooperativeness of the community are amazing!